# How can I pass a vector to a thread using CreateThread()?

Tags: windows, multithreading, vector

I'm trying to create a program that asks a user for a number and generate Fibonacci numbers. Main with get the number and set that number to the first value of the vector. The vector will then be sent to a thread to generate the Fibonacci equal to that number (so if I type `3`, the thread will generate the first 3 Fibonacci numbers and add it to the vector). Then the vector will get returned to the main function so that it can print out the values.

Here is what I have, but it keeps saying `Error: expression must be a pointer to a complete object type` where I try to print out the first value of the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

/* This function is executed by the child thread */
DWORD WINAPI calcFibNumbers(LPVOID fibNumber)
{
    cout << fibNumber[0];

    return 0;
}

/* This is the main function and start of program */
int main()
{
    //Local Variables
    vector<int> fibNumbers;
    int numOfFib;

    //Create child thread
    HANDLE childThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, calcFibNumbers, &fibNumbers, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL);

    //Ask user for the number of fibonacci numbers
    cout << "Enter how many fibonacci numbers you would like the program to generate: ";
    cin >> numOfFib;
    fibNumbers.push_back(numOfFib);

    ResumeThread(childThread);
    if (childThread)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(childThread, INFINITE);
    }

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is no C++, std::thread is C++

Comment: @DieterLücking  The language is C++, but I'm using the Win Thread Library for the multithreading

Comment: You need to cast LPVOID fibNumber back into to vector<int>* in calcFibNumbers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199369/error-expression-must-be-a-pointer-to-a-complete-object-type

Comment: @TonyJiang I added this `vector<int>fibNum = (vector<int>*)fibNumber;
 cout << fibNum[0];` but I still get an error: `IntelliSense: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>> *" to "std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>`

Comment: vector<int>* fibNum = (vector<int>*)fibNumber; or vector<int>& fibNum = *(vector<int>*)fibNumber;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vector<int>* fibNum = (vector<int>*)fibNumber; // pointer

vector<int>& fibNum = *(vector<int>*)fibNumber; // reference
```